# CakePHP translate longer text

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Currently I am translating all used strings with the __("") function, which works quite well. What is the best way to offer multilingual, longer texts for example for emails or for a thank you page?

One way to do would be to have all languages in one ctp file, switching between them by having a if query on the language set. So there would be only one file. But I dont know if there are any better solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, if it's only meant for a few pages, but Cake offers [a `TranslateBehavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html) which uses database tables to provide alternate translations.

In this scenario all of the pages have to belong to a model with an associated table, but it's the other major solution Cake offers as opposed to the normal Internationalisation/Localisation procedure.